# How can I play a sound in Twilio's Autopilot?

Tags: twilio-api

I would like to see if I can play a voice recording to remove twilio's Autopilot robot voice, any idea on how to do this? Or if it's even possible?

Answer (score -1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can specify a voice with Amazon Polly using [StyleSheets](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/api/assistant/stylesheet), a declarative API responsible for dialogue, state management, and error handling that can be used to control an Assistant's tone, language, and more.

In Node.js, you could update a StyleSheet to use a different voice like this (make sure your Twilio helper library is updated to a more recent version as this is a new functionality!). Here, your Autopilot Assistant's voice would be Joanna.

```
client.autopilot.assistants('REPLACE-WITH-YOUR-AUTOPILOT-ASSISTANT-SID')
    .styleSheet()
    .update({
        styleSheet: {
            style_sheet: {
                voice: {
                    say_voice: 'Polly.Joanna'
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .then(style_sheet => console.log(style_sheet.assistantSid));
```